# Application pool diagnotics

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5, pool

I have inherited a server running IIS 7.5 (I am not the server admin but someone in IS but they don't know IIS 7.5  very well) the website is coded in ASP.NET MVC 2; it is running really slow at start up. It takes about 1-2 minutes to fully launch. Is there a diagnostic tool to see what is causing the bottlenecks like a trace function that runs while the application is starting up to log the information and how long it takes each process to boot?

I have a feeling it's some poorly written LINQ code due to poor database structure, which I want to diagnose to see if that really is the problem or if there is something else causing the slow app restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the ASP.NET mini profiler:

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Comment: I ended up using the ASP.NET MVC3 upgrade tool to get from MVC2 to MVC3 with minimal issues. I then installed Glimpse which is doing the trick. I will try mini profiler too.